# IOS/xcode/coredata: Best practice to store userid in app--testing phase

Tags: ios, xcode, userid

I am developing an app that will eventually interact with a website through a web service that supports many users.  The app user will then need a userid and password to synch up data.  For an url connection to a server that requires authentication, answers on SO suggest that nsurl credentials or keychain are the way to go.  However, initially, I just want to give the user and app a userid--that is persistent but can be changed when desired--so that I can do things like incorporate the userid in profile picture names and so forth following the format used in the web app.

Ideally, I'd like to do this now in a way that I don't have to repeat work later.

Is there a best practice for storing a user's userid in an app that I could do now prior to actually connecting to any web services?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: If the userId is something that's going to be displayed in the app, why do you care about the security of how it's stored? Obviously you'd never want to save a username and password in plain text, but what you're doing doesn't sound like it merits anything more than `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NSUserDefaults to save persistent user data

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[userDefaults setObject:@"12234" forKey:@"userID"];

[userDefaults synchronize];
```

You can then get the User ID back by using

```
NSString* userID = (NSString *) [userDefaults objectForKey:@"userID"];
```

**Class Reference:**
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html

Comment: can i change this at any time by just using same line: [userDefaults setObject:@"12234" forKey:@"userID"];
?

Comment: Yes, you can. Don't forget to synchronize. That's what writes the defaults to storage. Otherwise it will only linger around in memory.